# Emojione Area not displaying the emoji pane

Tags: javascript, area, emojione

I am using the [Emojione Area](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) JavaScript plugin.  However, I am only getting the text area displayed, without the emoji pane.

Here is my HTML file :

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#emojionearea1").emojioneArea({
                    pickerPosition: "left",
                    tonesStyle: "bullet"
                });
        </script>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <textarea id="emojionearea1">Default :smile:</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two things to fix on your code:

1. You need to import the Javascript File from jQuery before EmojioneArea
2. Your Script in Javascript doesn't close the function $(document).ready()

So the should should be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <textarea id="emojionearea1">Default :smile:</textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#emojionearea1").emojioneArea({
            pickerPosition: "left",
            tonesStyle: "bullet"
        });
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Popup will appear on the Right side because Left is not a valid value for the propertie pickerPosition. According to the documentation (www.github.com/mervick/emojionearea) the only valid values are `top`, `right` and `bottom`. The value `top` is the default one

I Hope it helps you

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the emojioneArea panel not being visible no mater what the position was set to. I added the property `inline: true` and it showed up.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#emojionearea1").emojioneArea({
        pickerPosition: "left",
        tonesStyle: "bullet",
        inline: true
    });
})
```